# How do you fill an icon "cloud" text with color in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this a cloud icon text(/uE753), but the inner side is transparent. How to fill the inner side with some color?

In my example, I would like to draw white sky on blue border:

```
<Border BorderThickness="0" Background="SkyBlue" CornerRadius="50" Padding="5">
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE753;" Foreground="White"/>
</Border>
```

I tried putting the TextBlock's Background="White", but it becomes white block square instead.

Comment: There is no filled cloud available at this font and you can't fill the outlines of this char.

Comment: Changing font family to `FullMdl2Assets` and glyph to `E941` works on my box. I hesitate to post it as answer, as I'm uncertain of the general availability of that font...

Comment: @WPFGermany thanks for the info. Do you have some reference that I can use to track if it may become available?

Comment: Sorry, no. But I did find several filled clouds in `Segoe UI Symbol` -- perhaps `E285` can fit your needs?

Comment: @PetterHesselberg well, it looks like a solution to me, why not post it as an answer and put a note about the general availability. And, would you let me know where you get the `FullMdl2Assets` ?

Comment: @PetterHesselberg `E285` does not render as a cloud on Segoe MDL2 Assets.

Comment: @kurakura88: Maybe you can lookup at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font . In the list of chars you actually won't find a filled cloud.

Comment: You will find E285 in Segoe **UI Symbol**, not Segoe **MDL2 Assets**. (It's part of a set apparently designed for weather apps, and not identical to your outline cloud. But perhaps usable.)

Comment: @WPFGermany OK, thanks! In the beginning I was just wondering if you have another link to show that MS is preparing for the filled cloud.

Comment: @PetterHesselberg Ok, thanks! It is definitely an alternative. But, I will wait for other people who has better way to fill the cloud/ generic char with some color for the ultimate solution.

Comment: @kurakura88: I found the `FullMdl2Assents` font as part of Microsoft System Center Manager 2016 HTML5 Portal. It's based on Segoe ML2 apparently, but contains quite a few additional icons: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/servicemanager/2015/11/05/announcing-new-html5-based-self-service-portal/

Answer (score -1):

instead of `Segoe MDL 2 Assets` you could use icons of `Material Design`

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Cloud" />
```

MaterialDesign:

https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

Comment: Where do you get this `Material Design`?

Comment: @kurakura88: Updated my answer. Refer the link

Comment: yeah and then, how do you set its fill colour?